# In this function, will we include end points for decreasing interval?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, applications, interval-arithmetic

Which of these statements is/are correct? The values are correct but am not sure about the interval. Are both correct, or is only one correct?

f(x)= sinx+cosx , 0 ≤ x ≤ 2π

1. f(x) is decreasing on interval $$(\frac π4, \frac{5π}{4})$$
2. f(x) is decreasing on interval $$[\frac π4, \frac{5π}{4}]$$

Comment: For $x \in [\frac π4, \frac{5π}{4}]$ we have $\cos x \le \sin x$, hence $f'(x) \le 0.$ Thus $f$ is decreasing on $[\frac π4, \frac{5π}{4}]$

Comment: Will we include pi by 4 and 5 pi by 4 for saying decreasing? Because at that time f'(x)=0

Comment: we will not include them. But we will also say "_there is a local max at $x = \pi/4$ and a local min at $x = 5\pi/4$_".

Comment: @PurabBajaj - What's your definition of "decreasing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)$ is :
$$f'(x) = \cos(x) - \sin(x)$$
If the derivative is positive, the function is increasing, if it is negative, the function is decreasing. If it is zero at a point, then the point could be a local min, max or an inflection point. Let us find when is the function increasing:
$$\cos(x) - \sin(x)>0 \implies \cos(x) > \sin(x)$$ In the interval $0 \le x \le 2\pi$, this is true for
$$\color{green}{x \in [0,\pi /4)}$$ and $$\color{green}{x \in (5\pi /4, 2\pi]}$$

When the function is decreasing, the derivative is negative, i.e.,
$$\cos(x) - \sin(x)<0 \implies \cos(x) < \sin(x)$$This is true for 
$$\color{green}{x \in (\pi/4, 5\pi /4)}$$

There is local max at $x = \pi/4$ and a local min at $x = 5\pi/4$ (can be found easily using the *first derivative test*). But I'm skipping that part since the question did not ask for that. Here is a graphical representation of the function in the specified interval:

[image]

Comment: It is decreasing on the closed interval. For any $x,y\in[\pi/4,5\pi/4]$, including the endpoints, if $x<y$ then $f(x)>f(y)$. That's the definition of decreasing. Having negative derivative is not necessary. For example, $g(x)=-x-\theta(x)$ is decreasing on any interval, even though it's not differentiable or continuous at $0$. (Here $\theta$ is the unit step function. Or, for a continuous example, take $\theta$ to be Cantor's staircase function.)

Comment: Another example is $-x^3$, which is differentiable and decreasing on any interval.

Comment: @mr_e_man by the same logic would you also say that the function is increasing on $[5\pi/4,2\pi]$, so the function is increasing as well as decreasing at $5\pi/4$?

Comment: @mr_e_man well, the negative derivative works for continuous functions (like the one mentioned in the question) and that are differentiable through the entire domain. Also, your $g(x)$ is differentiable at all points except $0$ (the derivative is negative) so we can conclude it is decreasing for intervals not including zero using the derivative. Moreover, the derivative of the step function is the Dirac-delta (at 0 it is unbounded), so the derivative of $g(x)$ at 0 approaches negative infinity (negative). Oh well...

Comment: I don't know if and why did I get a downvote from you.

Comment: A function can't be increasing or decreasing at a single point (like $5\pi/4$, or $3\pi/4$). It's decreasing on an interval, by definition. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DecreasingFunction.html . Your answer wrongly excludes the endpoints of the interval.

Comment: @mr_e_man I'll quote from the same site: "If the derivative $f'(x)$ of a continuous function $f(x)$ satisfies $f'(x)<0$ on an open interval $(a,b)$, then $f(x)$ is decreasing on $(a,b)$."

Comment: Your quote is not a definition. It's "if", not "if and only if". The derivative test applies to open intervals, and says nothing about closed intervals, which must be handled in other ways.

Comment: I'm sure you must have learnt that $\cos(x)$ is decreasing on the interval $(0,\pi)$, increasing on $(\pi,2\pi)$. Byt the same logic, my answer is correct.

Comment: I have learned that $\cos$ is decreasing on $(0,\pi)$ and also on $[0,\pi]$; and that $\cos$ is increasing on $(\pi,2\pi)$ and also on $[\pi,2\pi]$; and that "$\cos$ is decreasing at $\pi$" (or $\pi/3$ or any point) is not false but meaningless. Both (1) and (2) in the OP are true, but you say only (1) is true. Thus your answer is not correct.

Comment: if you insist on reasoning this way, I cannot argue further.

Comment: It really depends on the definition of "decreasing". If it's defined by the derivative at a point, then you're correct. If it's defined by $x<y\implies f(x)>f(y)$ on an interval, then you're not correct.